# Auto import Powershell module in project

Tags: c#, powershell, dll

I have created a `.dll` with a `PSCmdlet`, from this `.dll` I created a `NuGet` package. But when I add the `NuGet` package to a project I have to import the `.dll` manually before my command is working. How can I automatically import my module in the same project I add the `NuGet` package to?

`PSCmdlet`class

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "DemoNames")]
public class Get_DemoNames : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = false)]
    public string prefix;

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {

        var names = new[] { "Chris", "Charlie", "Isaac", "Simon" };

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
        {
            WriteObject(names, true);
        }
        else
        {
            var prefixed_names = names.Select(n => prefix + n);

            WriteObject(prefixed_names, true);
        }
    }
}
```

VS Package Manager Console before importing the module manually

> PM> DemoNames
>
> The term 'DemoNames' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verif y that the path is
>   correct and try again. At line:1 char:10
>   + DemoNames <<<< 
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DemoNames:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

VS Package Manager Console after importing the module manually

> PM> Import-Module C:\projects\ef2idbs\EF.XML\bin\Debug\EF.XML.dll
>
> PM> DemoNames
>
> Chris
>
> Charlie
>
> Isaac
>
> Simon

My `NuGet` package is created with the `NuGet Package Explorer` and has the following structure:

> lib
>
> -EF.XML.dll

Note: The imported `.dll` and the `.dll` in the `lib` folder are the same file.

Is it a good idea to add an install.ps1 file to my `NuGet` package which moves the `EF.XML.dll` file to a `$profile` directory, so that the .dll is automatically loaded?